# How to write json to file (scala, circe)?

Tags: json, scala, circe

I'm trying to figure out the way how to write json to archive file/stream.

```
Try {
      val baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
      val zos  = new ZipOutputStream(baos)
      series.foreach { s =>
        val entry = new ZipEntry(s"${s.timeseries}.json")
        zos.putNextEntry(entry)
        zos.write(s.asJson.toString().getBytes)
        zos.closeEntry()
        zos.close()
      }
      baos
    }
```

I feel like this is the wrong way to do it: `data.asJson.toString().getBytes`

Comment: You can use a [**Printer**](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Printer.html).